# Laravel 5 Loop Through Array

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am passing a variable `$mailchimp` from my Controller to my View.

this is what I got with `{{dd($mailchimp)}}`

```
    array:8 [▼
      "id" => "xyz123"
      "email_address" => "john.doe@discworld.com"
      "unique_email_id" => "c9a36649c8"
      "email_type" => "html"
      "status" => "subscribed"
      "merge_fields" => array:2 [▼
        "FNAME" => "John"
        "LNAME" => "Doe"
      ]
      "stats" => array:2 [▼
        "avg_open_rate" => 0
        "avg_click_rate" => 0
      ]
      "list_id" => "769808qeqw92"
    ]
```

how can I loop through this array ($mailchimp) ? With the code below I get an exception: "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

```
@foreach($mailchimp as $user)
  @if(is_array($user))
    @foreach($user as $key => $value)
      {{$value}}
    @endforeach
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Update:
With this Code in My Controller

```
public function index()
{   //Fetch all subscribers from DB
    $subscribers = Subscriber::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','asc')->get();

    foreach ($subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
      //Check if the local subscriber is also present in mailchimp
      $mailchimp = Newsletter::getMember($subscriber->email);
    }

    return view('backend.newsletter.contacts.index')->withSubscribers($subscribers)
                                                    ->withMailchimp($mailchimp);
}
```

I need to iterate the mailchimp array. As there are multiple users, alexey's suggestion doesn't work out anymore.

This stil doesn't work:

```
@foreach($mailchimp as $key => $user)
    {{$user}}
  @endforeach
```

Comment: is it possible that {{$value}} is an array?

Comment: is this array..what kind of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over `$user`. If `$mailchimp` is an array of users, do this:

```
  {{ $mailchimp['email_adress'] }}
  {{ $mailchimp['merge_fields']['FNAME'] }} {{ $mailchimp['merge_fields']['LNAME'] }}
```

Comment: with your suggestion i get this: " Illegal string offset 'email_address'"

Comment: @Mamulasa, please post `{{ dd($mailchimp) }}` result.

Comment: {{dd($mailchimp) is in my question above

Comment: @Mamulasa, if `{{ dd($mailchimp) }}` is an array that listed in your question above as you say, updated code will work for you.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't remove the foreach

Comment: Yes. But still not clear why I con't use a foreach loop to itterate trough it

Comment: @Mamulasa, you have just one user data in `$mailchimp` that's why you don't need to iterate over it. You want to iterate over an array or a collection when you have multiple users in it.

Comment: Ok, this will definitely be the case. So how can I do this ?

Comment: @Mamulasa, if you get a collection of users with `$users = User::where('status', 'cool')->get()` iterate over users like this `@foreach ($users as $user)  $user->email_adress  @endforeach`

Comment: Well. Some new issues here with multiple users. I've updated my question. I still can't loop trough my §mailchimp array. Any suggsetion here ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in printing the values in your array, you can use [`array_flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-array-flatten) to get rid of the nested arrays, and then loop through the result:

```
@foreach(array_flatten($mailchimp) as $userData)    
    {{$userData}} 
@endforeach
```